# SeleniumException: java.awt.AWTException: headless environment: Selenium Headless

Tags: ant, selenium, debian, selenium-rc, headless

I'm trying to run Selenium tests in an Headless

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to automate a functionality that requires graphics support from test environment.

Either skip this specific test while running in non-GUI mode or execute tests in GUI mode.

One thing to understand while working with headless browsers, that there scope is limited and can't be used to execute whole project. We use them to execute smoke tests. One scenario where headless is best choice:

You need to redirect to multiple pages and get title of each page to verify with expected conditions. Here, I would go for headless browser as they are faster that head-full browsers and best suited for such tasks. Although If you ask headless to execute a functionality lets say upload file on GUI, I doubt it would work here.